# jQuery animating 2 independent div widths causing pixel jerkyness

Tags: jquery, css-float, width, jquery-animate

Using two divs aligned side by side by using the float CSS parameter.

jQuery alters the width of both of them at the same time. This is causing a jerky pixilated agitation. I set up a fiddle but jsfiddle is down.

How do we make each div width slide simultaneously without this shake.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div d1">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="div d2">DIV 2</div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</br></br>
<input class="s1" type="button" value="shift"/>
<input class="s2" type="button" value="shift back"/>
​
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.s1').click(function(){
        $('.d1').animate({width:100},{duration:300,queue:false});
        $('.d2').animate({width:300},{duration:300,queue:false});
    });
     $('.s2').click(function(){
        $('.d1').animate({width:100},{duration:300,queue:false});
        $('.d2').animate({width:300},{duration:300,queue:false});
    });
});​
.div { display:block; width:200px; height:90px; background:#666; colour:#FFF; float:left; }

.container { border:1px solid #000; background:#EEE; width:400px; }
input { clear:both;}
```

​
Here is a version with the right div float changed to right so you can see exactly what I mean. Look at the white line that you can see between them during animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/74zNU/1/

Comment: Here's your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/74zNU/ I modified the s2 animation a bit as your code did not shift back. I also don't see any weird things. Can you post a screenshot from what you see?

Comment: @barts You can still see the right hand margin reduced by a pixel or 2 when animating.

Comment: Indeed ... weird. Seems there's some offset issue with the width or left position in the animation

Comment: No it is caused by the two animations operating on a per pixel basis at the same time. The question is how to fix it

Comment: I thought I had found a solution but it showed that pixel thingy at the right side again. Looks like it is related to this bug in jquery (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7109)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ***two*** different solutions for you to consider for this Chrome issue.

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rk7uC/)

> This **jsFiddle** uses your method with a **workaround** for Chrome brower's white
>   line between the elements as it animates **while respecting** that both
>   elements **must** be of unique sizes. The use of **`position:absolute`** for
>   Div2 is used along with **`z-index`** of **`1`**. Throw in a 1 pixel padding and it
>   "***covers***" like a band-aid that white gap.

---

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/UnJf5/)

> This **jsFiddle** uses a **different method** altogether. Instead of
>   changing the sizes of both div's, only Div2 receives a ***position
>   change*** simulating a width size change since **`overflow`** property
>   is set on the **`container`** div. The illusion is similar to the
>   previous jsFiddle except the div's always maintain their **`400px`**
>   width.

Comment: Neither are possible. Both divs contain 100% width content along with borders and other detail, this was just a basic example.

Comment: In your Question, both divs contain 200px width content along with container of 400px for which this Answer is based upon.

Comment: Agreed and thank you for your answer but if it was that simple I wouldn't have asked the question. For all intensive purposes though you get a green tick.

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance. To be sure, your current Question is indeed simple and basic as it can be. But your message comments don't reflect the code you are using. Having said that, update your Question and jsFiddle to show how you are using `100% div width `having this Chrome issue so I can provide you with a ***updated answer*** worthy of an Upvote. Cheers!